# Angular set ng-minlength from controller does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is the controller:

```
    function Ctrl($scope) {
      $scope.text = 'guest';
      $scope.word = /^\w*$/;
      $scope.min_length = 4;
    }
```

Here is the view:

```
    <form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
      Single word: 
      <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="text"
             ng-pattern="word" ng-minlength="min_length" required />
      ...
    </form>
```

The `ng-minlength="min_length"` won't trigger the minlength error except I explicitly write
`ng-minlength="4"`. However, `ng-pattern="word"` works fine.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sliter/uVXn4/) link

Is it because I am doing wrong or there is way to get around?

Comment: There is an issue registered. Have a look here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1405

Comment: Have you found a temporary workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it with ng-minlength

```
<input ng-minlength="{{ min_length }}" />
```

Here it is working

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/CriddleCraddle/ukbw7xoy/)